# How to connect Redshift database using Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am not able to connect to the redshift database using Node. I am using Node JS version `14.15.1`.
Is there any issue related to this version?

The following code, I have tried in my local machine,
`redshift.js` file

```
var Redshift = require('node-redshift');
 
var client = {
    user: 'user',
    database: 'db',
    password: 'password',
    port: port,
    host: 'hostname',
};

var redshiftClient = new Redshift(client, {rawConnection:true});
 
module.exports = redshiftClient;
```

The following is the code to get the values from database,
`index.js` file

```
var redshiftClient = require('./redshift.js');

console.log('Before Connection');
redshiftClient.connect(function(err){
console.log('After Connection');
    if(err) throw err;
    else{
      redshiftClient.query('SELECT * FROM "customer"', {raw: true}, function(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
          console.log(data);
          redshiftClient.close();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

If I run this code not getting the error and even this line is also not executed `console.log('After Connection');`

Comment: I have used the node version 12.13.1 and issue is solved for me.

Comment: The same code I have used in AWS Lambda function but getting empty response. Why?

Comment: Please follow the link, this code works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68080267/cant-return-any-value-while-connecting-redshift-from-node-js

Comment: Instead of Raw Connection use **Connection Pooling** <https://github.com/dmanjunath/node-redshift#connection-pooling>

Answer (score 3):

The package seems a bit abandoned as here's an [open issue](https://github.com/dmanjunath/node-redshift/issues/37) with exact issue

To solve that you need to apply [this solution](https://github.com/dmanjunath/node-redshift/pull/38) manually

go to `node_modules/node-redshift` and replace

```
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "migrate": "^0.2.2",
    "pg": "^6.1.2",
    "sql-bricks": "^1.2.3"
  },
```

in `package.json` to

```
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "migrate": "^0.2.2",
    "pg": "^8.1.5",
    "sql-bricks": "^1.2.3"
  },
```

run `npm install` in this directory in order to update this package. After that your code will work

Comment: In ```node_modules/node-redshift``` folder you have mentioned ```"pg": "^6.1.2",``` but in the ```package.json``` file the version for the pg is different ``` "pg": "^8.1.5",```.
Is it the same?